# When doing Ice Skating, is it more painful to fall in motion or without motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, everyday-life, free-fall

Let's imagine I'm ice skating on a perfectly flat surface.

In the first scenario, I am falling motionless. I expect my forces to looks like this:
[image: Falling from 2 meters]

In the second scenario, I am falling with some speed, let's say 20 km/h. I anticipate my forces to appear as follows:
[image: 20km speed]

Questions:

- Will it take the exact same amount of time to hit the floor in both scenarios?
- Will I "hurt" myself upon impact on the floor with the same force/pain?

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, it definitely would hurt more to fall when moving at 20km/h than when stationary.

Now, in terms of the idealized physics scenario (no friction, no effects from your body collapsing), the only force present in both scenarios is gravity which points downward. In the second case, assuming that you are moving at a constant velocity, there is not a force pointing horizontally. In both cases, it should take the same amount of time to fall.

Comment: Whenever I have fallen off horses, it always hurts worse when the animal is moving.